# How to decouple Auth services from other services in Microservice Architecture?

Tags: authentication, flask, microservices, logout, coupling

I have set of microservices, one of them is responsible for the authentication. All services use a shared library e.g. [flask_jwt_extended](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_usage.html), and a shared secret key for validating the incoming requests (e.g. using `jwt_required` decorator of the [flask_jwt_extended](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_usage.html) ).

The main endpoints of the authentication service are UserLogin and UserLogout, some thing like that:

```
class UserLogin(Resource):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        self.parser.add_argument('email', type=str, required=True)
        self.parser.add_argument('password', type=str, required=True)


    def post(self):
        args = self.parser.parse_args()
        email = args.get('email')
        password = args.get('password')

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if not user:
            return jsonify({'message': 'User does not exist'})

        if user.verify_hash(password):
            access_token = create_access_token(identity=user.email) 
            return jsonify({'access_token': access_token})
        else:
            return jsonify({'message': 'Wrong credentials'})


class UserLogout(Resource):

    @jwt_required
    def post(self):
        #Get the token and presist 
        jti = get_raw_jwt()['jti']        
        blocked_token = BlockedTokens(jti=jti) 
        db.session.add(blocked_token)
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify({'message': 'logged out'})
```

Then in the other services I protect the endpoints using the `jwt_required` decorators, which simply validate the token of the incoming request (no thing special):

```
class PostDetails(Resource):

    @jwt_required
    def get(self, post_id):
        pass
```

And of-course all services share the same secret key:

```
app = app = Flask(__name__,)
app.config.from_mapping(JWT_SECRET_KEY=os.environ['JWT_SECRET_KEY'])
```

The logout operation Ideally should goes as follows:

1. store the access token in the database of the authentication service.
2. For each request, block it if its token is in the blacklist.

My questions is:

1. How to check for the blocked tokens in the other services (other than the auth service) without introducing further coupling between the services?
2. Is it possible to further decouple the services i.e. by not sharing any libraries or secret key?

**Edit**: I have added further details and code snippets to the question, I hope it is better clarified and justified.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the logout operation? Why is it not sufficient to just remove the appropriate token from the user's browser? Is there a specific threat you're trying to mitigate here?

Comment: removing the token from browser, does not  means that the token can  not be used. The token will be usable until it is expired.

Comment: you are right that's how you would blacklist the token . Normally we choose the short lived access tokens say 15mins expiry time period, and once the token is expired you will issue new token by refresh token. You can always revoke the refresh token. Generally there is single service that you would use to authenticate the token , so every service and any service would call that service to check the validity of token. In your case any other service will call your authentciation svc to check the validity of token.

Comment: I think sending request from the other services to the authentication service to validate the token of each incoming request, may introduce network overhead and a bottleneck (auth service), am I correct @ImranArshad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments above.

The short answer is yes it may be an overhead for auth service but that's the best way to decouple the services and keep your authentication logic confined into same service.

Another way is to put the token in distributed cache and validate the token if it's blacklisted. You can only keep the tokens in cache that falls within the expiry time period of tokens. Say you have token expiry of 15mins , you will only check the tokens in cache that were generated in last 15 mins, the rest of the tokens are expired anyway and can be deleted . that would keep the size of cache small and be quicker to check. This cache service can be shared across all your services.

Generally we have gateway service (public endpoint) validating the tokens and that service can call cache service to check if token is in cache blacklist.

Comment: So there is a trade-off between performance and decoupling, thank you. But what about moving the auth logic into the Api gateway like Kong do, by doing that how the request flows in the architecture?

Comment: generally we have auth logic sitting in api gateway . this way not every svc has to validate the token, having said that all other microservices must be private with no public endpoint and only way to get them is thru api gateway. so any web req first pass thru apigate way. once everything is validated we will redirect it to respective microsvc

Comment: Thank you, now things are more clear. Sorry for bothering again but if I decided to have an auth service under the api gateway where all request get directed to this auth service before being directed to the correct service by the api gateway, is it possible to have this workflow with an api gateway? if yes can you name one I can use?

Comment: No worries at all i am glad to help you. aplogies that i am unable to pick your last point.  "is it possible to have this workflow with an api gateway? if yes can you name one I can use?"

Comment: But wouldn't you have to verify if a sent access token exists in the blacklist for every single request that all users send that way?